# Inconsistency in relationship between Java and C

Tags: java, c, exception, format, format-specifiers

Please forgive me if my question seems pretty noobish. This is my first question over here.

I am having a simple query in my mind. **Java** language has been implemented using *C* and *C++*.

My question is

> In C language,the formatting behaviour of C is undefined for using
>   different modifiers than the given datatype.

```
int c=10;
printf("%f",c);    // unspecified behaviour
```

Whereas in Java, if we use the similar concept to print the number using different format specifier, we get an `IllegalFormatConversionExceptoion`.

**Exception Detail :-**

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer

My question is :-

## Why so difference between Java and C though Java is derived from C!

Please clear my doubt. I'll be thankful to you geniuses...

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: I think a better way to look at this is, Java uses exception handling to capture or control the undefined behaviour where as in C we have no concept of exception handling.

Comment: Yes, you'll get a runtime error from Java, but not from C. On the other hand, most modern C compilers will give you a compile-time warning when you use the wrong format specifier.

Comment: @juanchopanza-I think that the question is pretty clear. Why so difference between Java and C though Java is derived from C! Also, I didn't expect receiving number of downvotes! Very pathetic!!!

Comment: @asad you just added the clarification for the question. Before all you had were facts and examples listed with no actual question, so it wasn't clear.

Comment: I guess this question is good question,it should receive upvotes,not downvotes!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `printf` in Java is inspired by the same method in C but works completely differently.  If you give it a `BigDecimal` for example it will print it even though C doesn't have a BigDecimal.

In short, just because Java is similar to C, doesn't mean it use the same underlying functions.  In most cases, Java has it's own implementations to ensure;

- defined behaviour
- that is consistent with how Java is used.
- works the same across all OS platforms.

> Why so difference between Java and C though Java is derived from C

Why not?  Why would this make any difference at all?

Let me give you a different example. The verb to "manufacture" literally meant man made, and yet today it almost means the opposite.  Just because one language is derived from another doesn't mean they have to be the same.

Comment: Though your answer was good, but I want a more clear explanation. Would you be more specific towards it!

Comment: @asad To give a clear/specific answer, I would need a clear/specific question.

Comment: So,the specifc question is---> how does java manage this though C didn't thought of managing it! i guess C was basic low-level language and hence,provided lesser functinality! But,Java was modern as compared to C,so it customised the changes I guess! If I am wrong,please feel free to correct me!

Comment: @asad The Java code is written in Java, it checks the object type and throws an Exception,  The C version is written in C, which doesn't have objects or runtime type checking and C doesn't have exceptions, so it couldn't be expected to do the same thing as Java.

Comment: No,but Wikipedia says that Java was implemented in C and C++! Please help me, I am getting more confused!

Comment: Repeat after me, `printf` in Java is written in Java, for the reason I have explained. It is not written in C.  JVM uses some C for it's implementation, most of the Java runtime and tools are written in Java

Comment: @asad when the JVM runs machine code generated from byte code, there is no C or C++ involved.  The translation of byte code into machine code is largely done in C, but once the machine code is generated, there is nothing between your running Java code and the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Because historically, the `printf` function caused all sorts of headaches when the format specifiers were wrong, or arguments were missing. So languages derived from C, specifically C++ and Java, went to extraordinary lengths to avoid the `printf` problem.

At the same time, C compilers were improved to understand how `printf` works, and generate warnings when it's used incorrectly. Hence, the `printf` problem no longer exists for the most part (unless you ignore/disable the warnings).